# Pointer to object type

Tags: c++, linux, oop, gcc

I've been trying to create an hierarchy of classes, having each class contain a nested struct which contains data.

```
////////Class.h////////////////////////////
#ifndef _CLASS_H_
#define _CLASS_H_
#include <stdio.h>

class A{//Base
    protected:
    struct dataA{
        int v1, v2;
    };
    public:
    A();
    virtual void met1();
    dataA * const set;
    const dataA * const get;
};

class B : public A{//Child1
    protected:
    struct dataB : public dataA{
        int v3, v4;
    };
    public:
    B();
    virtual void met2();
    dataB * const set;
    const dataB * const get;    
};

class C : public B{//Child2
    struct dataC : public dataB{
        int v5, v6;
    };
    public:
    C();
    void met3();
    dataC * const set;
    const dataC * const get;
};
#endif
////////Class.cpp///////////////////////////
#include "Class.h"

A::A() : set( new dataA ), get( set ) {
    this->set->v1 = -1;
    this->set->v2 = -1;
}

void A::met1() {
    printf( "%i, %i", this->get->v1, this->get->v2 );//PRINTS "-1, -1"
}

B::B() : A(), set( new dataB ), get( set ) {
    this->set->v3 = -1;
    this->set->v4 = -1;
}

void B::met2() {
    printf( "%i, %i", this->get->v1, this->get->v2 );//An attempt to access C's "get" variable, PRINTS "-1, -1"
}

C::C() : B(), set( new dataC ), get( set ) {
    this->set->v5 = -1;
    this->set->v6 = -1;
}

void C::met3() {
    printf( "%i, %i", this->get->v1, this->get->v2 );//PRINTS "2, 3"
}
///////main.cpp////////////////////////////////
#include "Class.h"

int main() {
    C memb;
    memb.set->v1 = 2;
    memb.set->v2 = 3;
    printf( "%i, %i", memb.get->v1, memb.get->v2 );//PRINTS "2, 3"
    memb.met2();//PRINTS "-1, -1"
    return 0;
}
```

[image]
So, what I've been trying to do is after declaring a member of type C, to access an inherited function from B which has access to C's data struct. A void pointer wouldn't do the job, as it cannot point to object types. I've tried passing the address of C to B, though, they are both different types. First off, if I access v1 from the main block, provided I've set a value to it, as shown in the example, I get a correct value- the value I've set. However, if I try to access the same variable, but from class B instead, it prints the value, as if it had not been set before, other than from the constructor. So I'm attempting to create a link from class B to class C's data struct - to class C's data parent- class B's data struct. The example code had not been compiled.
Regards!

Comment: Perhaps code that compiles might help. There is no such thing as a data member `var1` in `A::dataA`, so the dereference `this->get->var1` in the printf statement is not valid. It isn't the only problem (obviously).

Comment: @WhozCraig I believe it should be fine now

Comment: You do realize that your comments as to "prints -1, -1" and such are not correct, right? I'm slightly confused as to what you are trying to achieve, and what your actual question is.

Comment: I get what you're trying to do, but eventually I think you're going to come to realize that you need *one* integral data member that is of the most-derived dataX type that all containing object classes in your hierarchy reference.

Comment: Perhaps pure virtuals? Seems doable, though, how will I parse them all down to a single type?

Comment: @MatsPetersson I'm trying to "create a link from class B to class C's data struct - to its parent- class B's data struct"

Comment: @user203432 yeah the only problem there is the eventual idea is to provide over*loads*, not just over*rides*. In fact, it looks like he wants overloaded-overrides, which is itself a contradiction. I.e. C::get() would needs to return something known to have v1..v6 (i.e. a dataC), while A::get() can only return something known to have v1..v2 (i.e. a dataA). Pure virtuals must be identical in signature, so thats out, and overloads cannot differentiate only by return type, so thats out too.

Comment: So, from class C, you want to use Class B's data as if it was Class C's data, but also with the ability to access Class C's data?

Comment: Exactly, except if it enters class C's data, it will indeed have access to its base- class C's data, as dataC inherits dataB

Comment: I got a headache looking at this. What *problem* are you trying to solve? Don't tell us your *solution*; tell us the *problem*.

Comment: I'll be posting an image in a moment

Comment: @NikBougalis I struggle to get access from B class to C class, as calling B's met2, I get a different result compared to the direct memb.get->var, even though I refer to (this) in B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is close to what you want, though I have to tell you I need to shower after writing it. There are a ton of things in this I would NOT do, but...

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class A{//Base
protected:
    struct dataA
    {
        int v1, v2;
    }  * const data;

    A(dataA* const p)
        : data(p)
    {
        p->v1=-1;
        p->v2=-1;
    };

public:
    virtual void met1()
    {
        printf( "%i, %i", get()->v1, get()->v2 );
    }

    const dataA * const get() const { return data; }
    dataA * const set() const { return data; }
};

class B : public A {//Child1
protected:
    struct dataB : public dataA
    {
        int v3, v4;
    } * const data;

    // protected constructor
    B(dataB * const p)
        : A(p), data(p)
    {
        p->v3 = 0;
        p->v4 = 0;
    };

public:
    virtual void met2()
    {
        printf( "%i, %i, %i, %i", get()->v1, get()->v2, get()->v3, get()->v4);
    }

    const dataB * const get() const { return data; }
    dataB * const set() const { return data; }
};

class C : public B
{
    struct dataC : public dataB
    {
        int v5, v6;
    } * const data;

public:
    C() : B(new dataC),
    data(static_cast<dataC*>(B::data))
    {
        data->v5 = 0;
        data->v6 = 0;
    };

    ~C()
    {
        // note, the pointers in B and A are left
        //  dangling after this is done.
        delete data;
    }

    virtual void met2()
    {
        printf( "%i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i",
               get()->v1, get()->v2,
               get()->v3, get()->v4,
               get()->v5, get()->v6);
    }

    const dataC * const get() const { return data; }
    dataC * const set() const { return data; }
};


///////main.cpp////////////////////////////////

int main() {
    C memb;
    memb.set()->v1 = 2;
    memb.set()->v2 = 3;
    printf( "%i, %i\n", memb.get()->v1, memb.get()->v2 );
    memb.met2();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
2, 3
2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

---

**Update**

OP wanted to see this without the get() and set() members using just member variables. Again, just hideous, but here you go:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstddef>

class A{//Base
protected:
    struct dataA
    {
        int v1, v2;
    };
    dataA * const set;
    const dataA * const get;

    A(dataA* const p)
        : get(p), set(p)
    {
        p->v1=-1;
        p->v2=-1;
    };

public:
    virtual void met1()
    {
        printf( "%i, %i\n", get->v1, get->v2 );
    }
};

class B : public A {//Child1
protected:
    struct dataB : public dataA
    {
        int v3, v4;
    };
    dataB * const set;
    const dataB *const get;


    // protected constructor
    B(dataB * const p)
        : A(p), set(p), get(p)
    {
        p->v3 = 0;
        p->v4 = 0;
    };

public:
    virtual void met2()
    {
        printf( "%i, %i, %i, %i\n", get->v1, get->v2, get->v3, get->v4);
    }
};

class C : public B
{
    struct dataC : public dataB
    {
        int v5, v6;
    };
public:
    dataC * const set;
    const dataC * const get;

    C() : B(new dataC),
        set(static_cast<dataC *const>(B::set)),
        get(static_cast<const dataC *const>(B::get))
    {
        set->v5 = 0;
        set->v6 = 0;
    }

    ~C()
    {
        // note, the pointers in B and A are left
        //  dangling after this is done.
        delete set;
    }

    virtual void met2()
    {
        printf( "%i, %i, %i, %i, %i, %i\n",
               get->v1, get->v2,
               get->v3, get->v4,
               get->v5, get->v6);
    }
};


///////main.cpp////////////////////////////////

int main() {
    C memb;

    memb.set->v1 = 2;
    memb.set->v2 = 3;

    printf( "%i, %i\n", memb.get->v1, memb.get->v2 );
    memb.met2();

    B& obj = memb;
    obj.met1();
    obj.met2();

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
2, 3
2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0
2, 3
2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Comment: Greatly appreciated! Though, is there a way to simplify the syntax and use set and get as variables?

Comment: @user203432 yes, but it would be even more horrid.

Comment: Agh, alright then, thanks anyways, guess this will do. This little detail has been holding me back maybe for a week or two now, glad it's partly over :)

Comment: You deserve a medal :P I'm so relieved! Thanks for the var version as well! It ain't so bad - not bad at all! Take care! :)